# Classes used to manage exception

Tags: java, methods, try-catch, short

Is it good to have a class with short methods used to catch Exceptions?

```
class ContractUtils{
  public static String getCode(Contract contract) throws MyException{
    try{
      return contract.getInfo().getCode(); //throws ContractException and LogicException
    }catch(Exception e){
      throw new MyException("error during code reading:"+e.getMessage, e);
    }
  }
  //other methods like above...
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to write "throws" in your method's signature

Comment: Ehhhh.  Exceptions should be handled as soon as you can usefully respond to them.  Generally that doesn't tend to be in some random utility method, but either lower down (in `contract.getInfo().getCode()` itself) or higher (at the application level where you can produce a useful error message).

Comment: What if `contract.getInfo().getCode()` throws e.g. a `NullPointerException` or an `ArithmeticException`? Surely in these situations you wouldn't want to catch and throw a `MyException` instead?

Comment: Nope, just put your try/catch directly in your real method (where you have a contact and want to get it's code). Better surround "contract.getCode()" with a try/catch than using you "getCode(Contract contract)" static method.

Comment: The use case scenario is this one: I'm working with Contract class gived me from external actors, these class throw two types of Custom Exception for every get method, my idea was to have a class to manage these Exception and put a useful error message inside a new custom exception. at the higher level i will catch every exception and log the message with this patter: "Error during contract edit: "+e.getMessage. So the result i would expect is like this: "Error during contract edit: error during code reading: value is null"

Comment: `contract.getInfo().getCode()` is called multiple times, i don't think it is good to repeat the same try/catch block several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your utility class `ContractUtil` introduces a level of **indirection** just to translate the original exception into another exception:

Instead of the direct call:

```
 return contract.getInfo().getCode()
```

you are now writing the more **artificial**

```
 return ContractUtils.getCode(contract);
```

**But** there might be situations where this solution can be **justified**, e.g.:

> You are
>   not allowed to throw ContractException or LogicException, and you are calling this method a lot
>   of times.

But if you can change its signature it would e better to redesign the original method to throw only `MyException`.

Comment: it's not called very often but i have to use it multiple times so i thought to use a single method to manage the exception one time and always get the same message error

Comment: @user1951947 then wouldn't it be better to move this error message normalization into the method? And as I said if this is not an option then your solution seems ok to me.

Answer (score 3):

If a custom exception provides additional context or value to the calling code, then it's useful and encouraged to create them.

You're approach to using static methods is totally acceptable. Here's a good [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20522548/2356554) defining use cases for short static methods.

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful to separate application logic from error handling for readability.

But not in utility class because you can forget to use it, and accomplish its task directly and still expect a custom exception. I would place this logic in Contact class if it is used often enough (and make Contract.getInfo() private). Another downside is, that it can lead to utility classes being too knowledgeable(LoD - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) about implementation details of other classes, possibly breaking encapsulation and making them less maintainable because of higher dependence.

And, you may want to catch specific exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with you that this thing should be done into the Contract class, unfortunately it become as it is from an external actor and the option to alter it is not possible, then i decided to write a sort  of "proxy" for the Contract class.

Comment: I see, you can wrap it using composition, if it isn't too big.

Comment: Yes it could be a good solution also to wrap it and override the methods i have to call, i like it.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to catch and handle exceptions separately in your code. Assigning a common custom exception is not recommended.

Refer this link for best practices in managing exception:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209693/best-practices-to-create-error-codes-pattern-for-an-enterprise-project-in-c

Comment: The OP never stated to what extent those exceptions were being managed. Virtually every COTS and OSS library creates custom exceptions. Also, you linked to an answer that was found to be too broad by the SO user community.